# Как исправить ошибку при static std::mutex?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

class Test
{
public:
    static std::mutex mutex;
};

int main()
{
    Test::mutex.lock();
    Test::mutex.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

При его компиляции выходит такая ошибка:

```
/tmp/cchDdN5m.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `Test::mutex'
main.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `Test::mutex'
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

Есл убрать static и сделать std::mutex глобальной переменной все работает корректно. Комплирую так:
`g++ main.cpp -lpthread`
Как можно исправить данную проблему, не убирая static?

Comment: К сведению: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static поля должны быть определены. Добавьте вне класса определение

```
std::mutex Test::mutex;
```

в итоге должно быть так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
class Test
{
public:
    static std::mutex mutex;
};

std::mutex Test::mutex;

int main()
{
    Test::mutex.lock();
    Test::mutex.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```